# Title of late 80's/90's japanese live-action tv mini series featuring a female cyborg named Maria

Tags: story-identification, tv, miniseries

Looking for the Title of a late 80's, early 90's Japanese live-action tv mini series featuring a female cyborg or robot named Maria clad in black armor (perhaps her body actually).

I think it was a mini series since it was broadcasted on over the air tv in Mexico in early 90's.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the (Hong Kong, not Japan) film [***I Love Maria*** (AKA Roboforce)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Love_Maria) from 1988.

It wasn't a mini-series, but otherwise a solid match. The (extremely) titular Maria is a black-bodied cyborg/robot in her frequently uncovered state.

Comment: That was the one. Been looking for ages, searching for Japanese Tv shows or films, looking in the wrong places all along, thank you!